# Eclipse DTP still doesn't handle delimiter statements

Tags: mysql, eclipse, triggers, syntax-error, eclipse-dtp

This

```
use sample_db;

CREATE TRIGGER bar_in
BEFORE INSERT ON bar
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     DECLARE foo INT;

END;
```

fails with

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 5

How to solve this syntax error (MySQL server is 5.5)?

is it possible that triggers are disabled or some such?

EDIT: This is a problem with Eclipse DTP existing since [2009](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/dtp-dev/msg01986.html), [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=414571)

Comment: Just use SET foo = "";

Comment: @Robert Rozas: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
     SET foo = ""' at line 3

Comment: My mistake...this is the right syntax: SET @foo = "";

Comment: @RobertRozas I *dont* want to use user variables

Comment: Well....this works in my environment: declare foo int;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error was related to the delimiter. Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER bar_in
BEFORE INSERT ON bar
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     DECLARE foo INT;
END $$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This results in "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$"

Comment: @JakubBochenski Where are you running the SQL? Are you running it in phpMyAdmin? If so, what version?

Comment: I'm using eclipse sql workbench, will try in command line l8r; regular DDLs like CREATE TABLE work fine

Comment: @JakubBochenski `CREATE TABLE` is different as it does not need to change the delimiter, so it will run. I don't know about eclipse sql workbench, but check if it supports the `DELIMITER` command. If not, then I'm afraid you cannot create triggers and stored procedures that way.

Comment: @JakubBochenski Oh, I didn't pay attention to the missing `FOR EACH ROW` line. Please add it. I updated my answer and tested it successfully in MySQL Query Browser.

Comment: good catch, looking at the same code for too long makes you blind; OTOH the mysql syntax error reporting could be friendlier